# How To Total Sum Inside Of Array Values In Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How to total sum inside of array values in  angularjs , actually we have used ng-repeat inside of one more ng-repeat to fetch the value in table and  I got the fetched value like `250` in `Sprice` then I'm expecting to totalsum the `sprice` value like  as a `ans= 250`.

[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iNzYbGHyOg40l2DL8HIx?p=preview).

- We have used two ng-repeat to get the `sprice` values in table because `sprice` is in inside of the [array].
- We need to calculate total sum of `sprice` of value in table.
- We have filter functionality to calculate the totalsum of ng-module value if it is in without array.
- Actually we dont' know how to use `resultValue=` in ng-repeat.
- For example: sprice value is 250 in table means the totalsum value need to be in `250`, if sprice value is 250 and 300 means expecting answer like `550`.
- Without `array` totalsum functionality: [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7SLMSbNgUoLU7giZ7I9I?p=preview)
- With `array` totalsum functionality: [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TucZa9MacuHptOVgThJo?p=preview)

**My Controller:**

```
  .filter('sumOfValue', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        debugger;
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;        
        var sum = 0;

        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
            sum = sum + parseFloat(v[key]);
        });        
        return sum.toFixed(2);
    }
})
```

**My Data:-**

```
    $scope.orders = [
{
"_id": "5836b64083d9ce0f0078eae8",
"user": {
"_id": "579bdf6123f37f0e00a40deb",
"displayName": "Table 1"
},
"__v": 8,
"total": "1824",
"ordercar": [],
"orderfood": [
{
"qty": "1",
"confirm": "placed",
"sprice": 250,
"price": 250,
"customise": "With Onion,Without Onion",
"name": "Baasha Pizza"
}
],
"phone": null,
"order_source": "",
"comment": "",
"payment_mode": "",
"nop": null,
"rating": null,
"bill": false,
"complete": false,
"laundry": false,
"clean": false,
"roomservice": false,
"napkin": false,
"waiter": false,
"water": false,
"name": "fgg",
"created": "2016-11-24T09:43:28.413Z",
"isCurrentUserOwner": true
}]
```

**My Html:-**

```
<table ng-table="tableParams"  class="table table-bordered ">
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <th rowspan="2">s.no</th>
        <th rowspan="2"> sprice </th>
        </tr>
</thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="order in orders">


            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="ram in order.orderfood">{{ram.sprice }}</td>


           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>sum</td>

             <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'sprice'}}</td>


           </tr>
          </table>
```

*We expecting for total sum in array values.

**Used ng-repeat:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders">


            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="ram in order.orderfood">{{ram.sprice }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` is not looping properly .. I fixed it .. Check below snippet and also i added one more array to it.......... let me know..

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.filter('sumOfValue', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        debugger;
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;        
        var sum = 0;
        
        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
            sum = sum + parseFloat(v[key]);
        });        
        return sum.toFixed(2);
    }
}).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.orders = [
{
"_id": "5836b64083d9ce0f0078eae8",
"user": {
"_id": "579bdf6123f37f0e00a40deb",
"displayName": "Table 1"
},
"__v": 8,
"total": "1824",
"ordercar": [],
"orderfood": [
{
"qty": "1",
"confirm": "placed",
"sprice": 250,
"price": 250,
"customise": "With Onion,Without Onion",
"name": "Baasha Pizza"
},
{
"qty": "2",
"confirm": "placed",
"sprice": 250,
"price": 250,
"customise": "With Onion,Without Onion",
"name": "Baasha Pizza"
}
],
"phone": null,
"order_source": "",
"comment": "",
"payment_mode": "",
"nop": null,
"rating": null,
"bill": false,
"complete": false,
"laundry": false,
"clean": false,
"roomservice": false,
"napkin": false,
"waiter": false,
"water": false,
"name": "fgg",
"created": "2016-11-24T09:43:28.413Z",
"isCurrentUserOwner": true
}]

});
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 14px;
}

table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table, td, th
{
    border:1px solid black;
}
td{
    padding: 2px;
}
.servicetaxinclusivetrue:before{
  color: green!important;
  content: "\f00c";
}
.servicetaxinclusivefalse:before{
  color: red!important;
  content: "\f00d";
}
.servicetaxexclusivetrue:before{
  color: green!important;
  content: "\f00c";
}
.servicetaxexclusivefalse:before{
  color: red!important;
  content: "\f00d";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    
    <table ng-table="tableParams"  class="table table-bordered ">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            
            <th rowspan="2">s.no</th>
            <th rowspan="2"> sprice </th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody ng-repeat="order in orders">
            <tr ng-repeat="ram in resultValue=(order.orderfood)">
              <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td >{{ram.sprice }}</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>sum</td>
                 <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'sprice'}}</td>
          
               </tr>
      </tbody>
              </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can call function using "ng-init", so that angularjs will call function before execution of "ng-repeat".

In that function you can perform iteration and calculate total and hold it in scope variable to display it.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, can u please update plunker as well to know the exact solution and please look into my plunker totalsum functionality and please give perfect solution for this..... thanks